# accepts_nested_attributes with 2 nested tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, one-to-many

I am new to Ruby on rails and I am creating simple website. I found out the rails 3 uses `attr_accessible` while rails 4 uses `strong parameters`. I am currently working with rails 4. I am not quite sure how to set up the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

This is what I have

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :expense_pictures 
  has_many :income_pictures

  accepts_nested_attributes_for: ExpensePicture ?
  accepts_nested_attributes_for: IncomePicture ?
end
```

ExpensePicture model:

```
class ExpensePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

ExpenseText model:

```
class ExpenseText < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :expense_pictures
end
```

IncomePicture model:

```
class IncomePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

IncomeText model:

```
class IncomeText < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :income_pictures
end
```

My User controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def create
    User.create(user_params)
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :IncomePicture ?
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ExpensePicture ?
  end

  private

    def user_params
      # required input for params
      # permit - returns a version of the params hash with ony the permitted attributes
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, ...not sure...)
    end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for `has_many relation` with your models,your `User` model should look like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :expense_pictures 
  has_many :income_pictures

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_pictures 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :income_pictures
end
```

Your `new` and `create` methods of usercontroller should look like this

```
def new
@user = User.new
@user.expense_pictures.build
@user.income_pictures.build
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
 redirect_to @user
 else 
 render 'new'
 end
end
```

And your `user_params` method should look something like this

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, expense_pictures_attributes: [:your_attr1,:your_attr2,..],income_pictures_attributes: [:your_attr1,:your_attr2,..])
end
```

Feel free to ask if you want any more information regarding to this.